# I have to make a verilog program that divides 2 numbers

Tags: verilog, division, subtraction

I have to divide two 8 bit numbers using Verilog(homework).
The module I have to use is this one:

```
module divider(
output reg[7:0] q,         
output reg[7:0] r,
input [7:0] a,b);
endmodule
```

where a=b*q+r

I'm not allowed to use repetitive subtracting or the / and % operators.

I am told that I can use SRT, Newton-Raphson or Goldschmidt algorithms to solve it, but i don't understand how they work...

Any help pls?

Comment: I think the point is to learn how one of those algorithms work, as they have ruled out the more direct arithmetic approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Start with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) and Google.  There is a ton of stuff on Newton's method.

Step 2: write a prototype in your favorite software language (Python, Scala, C, whatever).

Step 3: Only once you've accomplished the previous two steps should you then write your solution in Verilog.

The basic idea behind the Newton method is to make a guess, and then improve your guess every clock cycle/iteration. Your guess eventually converges to the correct answer.  Once the new guess is nearly the same as the previous guess, you're done.